# Multilevel / multiple level group by using lodash, underscore or array functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, lodash, underscore.js

I have below array of objects that was my output on getRawMany from typeOrm query:

```
[{
    "contents_id": "0e362978-ec0a-4851-9f58-e2ad23ec9ee9",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 1",
    "contents_created_at": "2020-11-28T23:42:23.717Z",
    "campaigns_id": "09e34ed1-0dfb-4723-abfb-eec21fc064bc",
    "campaigns_title": "First campaign title",
    "product_title": "product title one",
    "picture_upload": "image_text1.jpg",
    "views": "1"
},
{
    "contents_id": "0e362978-ec0a-4851-9f58-e2ad23ec9ee9",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 1",
    "contents_created_at": "2020-11-28T23:42:23.717Z",
    "campaigns_id": "09e34ed1-0dfb-4723-abfb-eec21fc064bc",
    "campaigns_title": "First campaign title",
    "product_title": "product title two",
    "picture_upload": "image_text2.jpg",
    "views": "1"
},
{
    "contents_id": "0e362978-ec0a-4851-9f58-e2ad23ec9ee9",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 1",
    "contents_created_at": "2020-11-28T23:42:23.717Z",
    "campaigns_id": "09e34ed1-0dfb-4723-abfb-eec21fc064bc",
    "campaigns_title": "First campaign title",
    "product_title": null,
    "picture_upload": null,
    "views": "1"
},
{
    "contents_id": "5b0bc1f1-62ad-4f3e-b2f6-c117a7b46e21",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 3",
    "contents_created_at": "2020-11-29T10:11:45.563Z",
    "campaigns_id": null,
    "campaigns_title": null,
    "product_title": null,
    "picture_upload": null,
    "views": null
},
{
    "contents_id": "6f211b84-4f76-4da7-9cc7-ab5fe9cc9807",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 2",
    "contents_created_at": "2020-11-29T10:07:55.090Z",
    "campaigns_id": null,
    "campaigns_title": null,
    "product_title": null,
    "picture_upload": null,
    "views": null
},
{
    "contents_id": "d1658dd6-2dd0-4b8b-b9b2-b3fcd1d2310a",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 1",
    "contents_created_at": "2020-11-29T10:07:55.090Z",
    "campaigns_id": null,
    "campaigns_title": null,
    "product_title": null,
    "picture_upload": null,
    "views": null
}];
```

This output was similar in sequelize.js raw query true.
I need to group by multiple level, groupings contents as array, and products and campaings as array too.

But I need the below output:

```
[{
    "contents_id": "0e362978-ec0a-4851-9f58-e2ad23ec9ee9",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 1",
    "views":1,
    "products":[{
                    "product_title": "product title two",
                    "picture_upload": "image_text2.jpg"
                }],
    "campaigns":[{
                    "campaigns_id": "09e34ed1-0dfb-4723-abfb-eec21fc064bc",
                    "campaigns_title": "First campaign title"
                }]
},
{
    "contents_id": "6f211b84-4f76-4da7-9cc7-ab5fe9cc9807",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 2",
    "products":[],
    "campaigns":[]
},
{
    "contents_id": "5b0bc1f1-62ad-4f3e-b2f6-c117a7b46e21",
    "contents_title": "Content mock 3",
    "products":[],
    "campaigns":[]
}]
```

So, How can I do it with the best simple way using lodash, underscore or javascript array functions?

Comment: Product title one of content mock 1 doesn't appear in your example output. Please either fix that or explain why it isn't supposed to appear. Also, it appears that products are nested within campaigns, but your example output does not show this. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you needed? 'rawContent' is your array to be grouped.

```
const grouped = rawContent.reduce((r, item) => {
    const key = `${item.contents_id}-${item.contents_title}`;
    r[key] = r[key] || { contents_id : item.contents_id, contents_title:item.contents_title, products: [],campaigns :[]  };
    if(item.product_title) r[key]["products"].push({product_title: item.product_title, picture_upload: item.picture_upload})
    if(item.campaigns_id) r[key]["campaigns"].push({campaigns_id: item.campaigns_id, campaigns_title: item.campaigns_title})
    return r;
  }, {})
  
  const result = Object.values(grouped)
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hello @IRSHAD, thanks for giving me this example. This was so helpful to me! Sorry for my late to give to you a feedback. So, In my case, I need an array, I only added Object.keys and map to return it as array and not a collection of objects. I added one more thing, in my case I have other rule that campaign and product may be unique in this new array. I adapted your answer checking in the ifs that will only push in this array if it exists using .some function. But .some function represents a loop as well. How do you adapt it for best performance?